# React Notifications Dropdown wrapper to close on clickaway

Tags: reactjs

I have a wrapper for a notifications dropdown in an app top-bar that is working fine for my click away from dropdown to close the list.  When I add a key to the list elements it breaks the functionality and clicking on a notification closes the dropdown.

Ex: This breaks and onclick it closes the dropdown menu

```
<li key={key} className="media notification">
  1
</li>
```

Ex: This works and clicking the notification does not close dropdown but warns a key is needed.

```
<li className="media notification">
  1
</li>
```

I'm not 100% sure I am doing something incorrectly but wanted to ask if there is something with a react key that would cause a behavior like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only explanation I can come up with is that your key is invalid.

Make sure its a string, make sure they are all unique and preferably base the key upon data input, not the index. Check [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more info.

Comment: Yup it was a bad key value.